# Ways to impress children about web privacy violations and concerns

Tags: privacy, data-leakage, sensitive-data-exposure

I would like to make a simple lesson to some children about the bad web surfing consequences for their privacy and personal data leaks.

E.g. privacy issues by using social networks, visiting websites full of ads, etc...

I have already written some text about those issues with today's privacy violations from websites, but I want to show them some **impressive** and **practical** things, also showing some **technical** stuff could be useful to obtain attention.

I have made some screenshots using [Firefox Lightbeam extension](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/lightbeam/) that show some interesting things about third parties cookies data sharing between websites.

Any other website that show interesting and impressive things about websites privacy violations and personal data leaking?

E.g.
Is there any site that I can use to show a child that use Facebook or others that his/her personal informations or photos are online or shared or gathered by other websites.
I'm open to any useful stuff.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should just demonstrate by hacking them when they don't expect it lol. Just use phishing or ARP spoofing; they're both proven methods. That would really impress them, and they'll think you're a badass too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an interesting [article](https://www.today.com/health/teachers-viral-letter-shows-students-dangers-social-media-1D80395915) about a teacher showing the dangers of posting images on social networking sites. May be worth doing your own experiment.

You could also use [BeEF](http://beefproject.com/) to demonstrate some client side attacks. This would be interesting to put the hook in malicious ad JavaScript. Hope this helps, good luck!

Additionally, there is a pretty cool website [What Every Browser Knows About You](http://webkay.robinlinus.com/).